# My graphics card is overheating or not?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, overheating

It goes up to 97 degrees Celsius when gaming and while it's overclocked, while it goes up to 94 degrees Celsius when gaming when it's not overclocked.

But the weird thing is that it drops in a 10 seconds from 95 degrees to 80 in 10 seconds.

So ...

Is it overheating at 97 degrees or it's still fine?

I have a Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT, and I don't play games i know isn't gonna run on it.

Comment: It's overheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT Specifications](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9600-gt/specifications)
says:

```
    Maximum GPU Temperature (in C)    105 C
```

So 97 C is uncomfortably high, but within the parameters.
This temperature is not advised in the long-term, but the card won't burn up
because of a brief episode.

The temperature going down fast is only the mark of the fans doing a good job.

Comment: I checked again... So i played F1 2013 for 20 min and it was going at a 91 C constantly, so is that better or is it still uncomfortably high?

Comment: I can't be sure, of course, but it seems that this is within parameters. The downside is that this heat is dumped inside your PC, so you need good cooling to push it outside. I suggest to also keep an eye on the CPU temperature.

Comment: CPU is fine, on idle it's at 60-70 C and while gaming I don't think it goes more than 90 C.

Comment: As long as the computer doesn't slow down or shuts down suddenly, and as long as you keep an eye on the temperature, I think you are ok.